# How to see in the xib UI what is implemented in the code of custom view in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've implemented a custom `UIView` and have assigned this `CustomUIView` to the `File's Owner`, I outlet-ed a `UIImageView` in the `CustomUIView` as below

```
@IBOutlet weak var messageCardView: UIImageView!
```

And I've implemented `init` function:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    messageCardView.image = UIImage(named: "img_1")
    messageCardView.alpha = 0.5
}
```

I'd like the alpha attribute and image showing in my xib static file, is there any way to do that? Great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just add `@IBDesignable` before your class declaration, like this:

```
@IBDesignable
public class CustomUIView : UIView {
    ...
```

It may not work until you save / reload your XIB, though.

More info: http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/#ibdesignable

Comment: Great help! Could you go a little bit further regarding how to save/reload my XIB? Thanks man!